# How can I package django with web-socket server using PyInstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, django, pyinstaller, django-channels

I have a django app, that uses web socket to communicate with different modules and it also starts with arguments. I modified the manage.py file to make it work with arguments as it is one of my modules. The structure of django stayed the same, only manage.py was modified.
This is manage.py file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":


# TMS configuration
tmsIp       = None
tmsPort     = None

# Database configuration
dbIp                = None
dbPort              = None
db_name             = None
db_user             = None
db_user_password    = None

ENVIRONMENT_DB_NAME     = ''
ENVIRONMENT_DB_USER     = ''
ENVIRONMENT_DB_PASSWORD = ''

db_name = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_DB_NAME)
if db_name is None:
    raise Exception("Database name was not found in environment variables")
db_user = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_DB_USER)
if db_user is None:
    raise Exception("Database user was not found in environment variables")
db_user_password = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_DB_PASSWORD)
if db_user_password is None:
    raise Exception("Database password was not found in environment variables")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--tmsIp", help="TMS server IP used to run messaging server on")
# Server port can be set using this parameter
parser.add_argument("--tmsPort", help="TMS server port used to run the messaging server on")
# Database IP
parser.add_argument("--dbIp", help="Database ip")
# Database Port
parser.add_argument("--dbPort", help="Database port")
# Display version
parser.add_argument('--version', help="Displays the version of the module", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.version is True:
    print(f'\n{MODULE_NAME} - {MODULE_VERSION}\n\n')
    exit()

# Parameter settings (if applicable)
if args.tmsIp is None:
    raise Exception(" Module cannot be started --tmsIp is missing")
if args.tmsPort is None:
    raise Exception(" Module cannot be started --tmsPort is missing")
if args.dbIp is None:
    raise Exception(" Module cannot be started --dbIp is missing")
if args.dbPort is None:
    raise Exception(" Module cannot be started --dbPort is missing")



tmsIp   = str(args.tmsIp)
tmsPort = int(args.tmsPort)
dbIp    = str(args.dbIp)
dbPort  = str(args.dbPort)


# Loading settings file
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

# Loading database configuration

from django.conf import settings
settings.DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'NAME':     db_name,
                'USER':     db_user,
                'PASSWORD': db_user_password,
                'HOST':     dbIp,
                'PORT':     dbPort,
        }

}

# Migrate the database
command = ['manage.py', 'migrate']
execute_from_command_line(command)


# Load menu in the database
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
location = os.path.join(curdir, "fixtures.json")

command = ['manage.py', 'loaddata', location]
execute_from_command_line(command)

# Start on tmsIp:tmpsPort with 1 process
command = ['manage.py', 'runserver', f'{tmsIp}:{tmsPort}', '--noreload']
execute_from_command_line(command)
```

and this is the spec file that I generated in order to package the module:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

```
 block_cipher = None


 a = Analysis(['app\\manage.py'],
         pathex=[' my_path '],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[
         'module1.urls',
         'app.views.handler404',
         'app.views.handler500',
         "channels.apps",
         "module2.urls",
         "module3",
         "module4.urls",
         "module5.urls",
         "module6.urls",
         "module7.urls",
         "module8.urls",
         "module9.urls",
         "module10.urls",
         "django_extensions",
         "compressor.finders"
         ],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
 pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
 exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='manage',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```